# How can I add an interceptor/filter after serialization in Quarkus

Tags: java, filter, quarkus, interceptor

I'd like to add an interceptor **after** serialization in Quarkus (using jsonb and resteasy **not** reactive).

I know about implementing `ContainerResponseFilter` but the `ContainerResponseContext` contains the returned *entity* **before** serialization (i.e. the java object) which is not what I want. My interceptor is encrypting (using a **custom encryption utility**) the serialized JSON string which means that the interceptor must run after serialization.

I know I could potentially manually serialize the response but I'd prefer to use the existing Quarkus facilities.

EDIT: `WriterInterceptor` doesn't seem to work because it is called **before** serialization has occurred (encryption needs to happen on the serialized json string).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [WriterInterceptor](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/WriterInterceptor.html) which allows you to intercept the data being returned as part of an HTTP response

Comment: No this doesn't help. The `WriterInterceptor`s get invoked before serialization. Except if there's a way to set my interceptor **after** serialization has occurred. Remember, I want to encrypt the **JSON String**

Comment: You can execute code after serialization is invoked

Comment: Really? Can you provide an example because my testing showed that all `WriterInterceptor`s get called before serialization.

Comment: See https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/restful-java-with-jax-rs-2-0-2rd-edition/content/en/part1/chapter12/reader_and_writer_interceptors.html

Comment: Still not possible. The `WriterInterceptor` gives access to the `OutpuStream` where the json will be written but it does **not** give access to the serialized object. Also from the docs: *The call to `WriterInterceptorContext.proceed()` will either invoke the next registered `WriterInterceptor`, or if there aren’t any, invoke the underlying `MessageBodyWriter.writeTo()` method*. It's pretty clear that all `WriterInterceptors` are invoked **before** the `writeTo()` method which means no interceptor gets access to the serialized object.

Answer (score 0):

I simple way to do this is to override the jsonb deserialization.

Create an interface that all the pojos that needs encryption must inherit:

```
package org.acme;

// All the pojos that needs encryption must inherit this
public interface EncryptedPojo {}
```

Create a pojo:

```
package org.acme;

public class MyPojo implements EncryptedPojo {}
```

Create the resource:

```
package org.acme;

import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class GreetingResource {

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public MyPojo hello() {
    return new MyPojo();
  }
}
```

Create the override to jsonb deserialization:

```
package org.acme;

import io.quarkus.jsonb.JsonbConfigCustomizer;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.Dependent;
import jakarta.enterprise.inject.Instance;
import jakarta.json.bind.JsonbConfig;
import jakarta.json.bind.serializer.JsonbSerializer;
import jakarta.json.bind.serializer.SerializationContext;
import jakarta.json.stream.JsonGenerator;

public class MyJsonBConfig {

  @Dependent
  JsonbConfig jsonConfig(Instance<JsonbConfigCustomizer> customizers) {
    JsonbConfig config = new JsonbConfig().withSerializers(new MySer());

    // Apply all JsonbConfigCustomizer beans (incl. Quarkus)
    for (JsonbConfigCustomizer customizer : customizers) {
      customizer.customize(config);
    }

    return config;
  }

  public class MySer implements JsonbSerializer<EncryptedPojo> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(EncryptedPojo pojo, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializationContext ctx) {
      if (pojo != null) {
        String encryptedPojo = encryptMyPojo(pojo);
        ctx.serialize(encryptedPojo, jsonGenerator);
      }
    }

    private static String encryptMyPojo(EncryptedPojo pojo) {
      return "My_encrypted_pojo";
    }
  }
}
```

And call the resourse e.g. http://localhost:8080/hello

output:

```
"My_encrypted_pojo"
```

Comment: Another approach, if you don't want to serialize the pojo "manually" is to use the existing "Quarkus facilities" like that:

  `@Inject Jsonb jsonb;`

You can directly inject the jsonb that quarkus is using and just do this: `jsonb.toJson(myPojo);`

Then you can encrypt and return the encrypted string

Comment: That's the actual solution since encryption must happen *after* serialization (i.e. the `encryptMyPojo(pojo)` doesn't actually exist).

Comment: But with the `JsonbSerializer` as presented I'm not sure how to do it because if we serialize the object with `Jsonb` we must not re-serialize it by calling `ctx.serialize()` since default json serialization of a string is not an identity function...